# Checking for change in data application-wide

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4

My application has a series of textfields, checkboxes and other controls. Ideally I would ask the user to save the information when something is changed on any (or all) the controls.

Is there a way to get this *is changed* behavior application wide? or I need to create an action per control and set the code there?

I'm using Xcode 4 if this makes any difference.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: more than one control can point to one action, then you can differentiate based on sender's tag or index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write code per control anyway (to handle user changes).

You may need to write additional code per changeable property, depending how you app is set up.

I'd suggest using NSNotificationCenter, and sending a "something-changed" notification when one of your data properties changes.

When your control is touched you set a property on some data-storage object:

```
-(IBAction)grommetSwitchPress:(UISwitch*)sender
{
    self.userData.wantsGrommets = sender.on;
}
```

That data-storage class will define a property:

```
@interface UserData : NSObject
{
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wantsGrommets;
```

with a custom property setter that tests if the value has changed:

```
-(void)setWantsGrommets:(BOOL)wantsThem
{
    if (wantsGrommets != wantsThem) // compares current property value with incoming
    {
        wantsGrommets = wantsThem;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                     postNotificationName:NOTIFY_SOMETHING_CHANGED
                   object:self];
    }
}
```

In some header you'll define the notification message:

```
#define NOTIFY_SOMETHING_CHANGED        @"somethingChanged"
```

and it's up to you to decide where to put the code in your app that listens for NOTIFY_SOMETHING_CHANGED, eg:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(somethingChanged:)
           name:NOTIFY_SOMETHING_CHANGED
             object:nil];   
}
```

In the somethingChanged: method, you could save data to NSUserDefaults, for example.

I would advise against "asking the user to save the information when something is changed on any (or all) the controls." It is bothersome to ask the user if they want their own changes saved … of course they do. If you want to give them a chance to back out, then provide a "Revert" or "Reset" button instead.

Comment: Awesome. let me try it and I'll get rigth back to you.

Comment: As it should. Thank you @ZeroDiv